# Row spacing for table rows

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-datatable, border-spacing

I would like to have rows in a table to have disconnected look similar to one attached below. I tried the below code by using `CSS border` property but I want to increate the vertical space between each rows with a thin border and give a sharp border edges.

```
.datatable-body-row {
    border: 4px double $light-gray-600;
    border-top: none;
}
```

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-virtual-scroll?file=app%2Fdemo-component.scss) demo page

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the CSS from .datatable-body-row and applying the CSS below to  .datatable-row-center should achieve the style you are looking for:

```
.datatable-row-center {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color:#ccc;
    margin-top:1px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}

.datatable-row-wrapper:hover .datatable-row-center {
    border-color: rgb(104, 152, 241);
}
```

The top and bottom margin can be adjusted depending on how much of a gap you want between each row, but I would recommend they be equal, if possible.

RE, dark blue border on selection, oddly this comes from the background colour of the parent cell, rather than an actual border. The following should remove it:

```
.ngx-datatable.material.single-selection .datatable-body-row.active,
.ngx-datatable.material.single-selection .datatable-body-row.active:hover
    {
        background: none;
    }
```

RE left and right borders, do you see them [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-virtual-scroll-yhszuq)? Looks like the image below to me so I'm not sure why they're not showing up - if not could you add a screengrab? I did add some left and right margin and remove the box shadow from the table container to make the left and right borders on each row more apparent.

In all, I added the following new CSS:

```
.ngx-datatable.material.single-selection .datatable-body-row.active,
.ngx-datatable.material.single-selection .datatable-body-row.active:hover
    {
        background: none;
    }

.data-container {
    margin-left: 24px;
    margin-right: 24px;
}

.data-container {
    .ngx-datatable.scroll-vertical {
        height: calc(100vh - 10px);
        width: $collection-list-table-width;
        box-shadow:none;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's close to what I'm looking for. What's if need a border to the left and right of the row? I tried `border-left: 1px; border-right: 1px;` but I don't get border.

Comment: Also is there an easy way to remove the dark blue border around the selected row?

Comment: I’ve literally just switched off for the night - appreciate the upvote. Will have another look tomorrow? RE left and right borders, I can see them so I’m not sure what’s going wrong. You could try adding a left border to the first cell in each row (e.g. with :first-child) and a right border to the last cell?

Comment: Tried the `:first-child` psedo selector but not getting desired results (I may not be doing the correct way). Yeah no problem, when you have time you may take a look at it. I just need left and right borders to give a boxed look, the rest looks good.